# How to display the selected griditem values in listview in android

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I am developing an application in which there would be a set of values from the database like plucking,loading,transporting etc and even users can add new categories in it.These items are displayed in grid view which works fine.When i select a particular item from the grid it should be displayed in the list view (if i select plucking means it should display the contents as title,no of trees and its value).

Main Activity:

```
public class GridActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
GridView gv;
ListView listview;
ArrayList<CustomizedCharge>listcharges;
AlertDialog alert;
String totalamount;
LinearLayout eview;
private List<CustomizedCharge> listactivitycharge;
 FetchlistData listadapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.otherchargesscreen);

    gv=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview1);
    listview=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    eview=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.empty);
    DatabaseHandlerOtherchgs databaseHandlerOtherchgs=new DatabaseHandlerOtherchgs(getApplicationContext());
    ArrayList<OtherChargesType> listet = new ArrayList<OtherChargesType>();

    Resources res = getResources();
    Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.p);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

    Drawable loading = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.l);
    Bitmap bitmaploading = ((BitmapDrawable)loading).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream streamloading = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmaploading.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, streamloading);
    byte[] bitMaploading = streamloading.toByteArray();

    Drawable addnew = res.getDrawable(R.mipmap.add);
    Bitmap bitmapaddnew = ((BitmapDrawable)addnew).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream streamadd = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmapaddnew.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, streamadd);
    byte[] bitMapaddnew = streamadd.toByteArray();

    listet=databaseHandlerOtherchgs.getAllproducttitle();
    listet.add(new OtherChargesType("Plucking",bitMapData));
    listet.add(new OtherChargesType("Loading",bitMaploading));
    listet.add(new OtherChargesType("Add New",bitMapaddnew));

    final OtherChargesGridAdapter adapter = new OtherChargesGridAdapter(GridActivity.this, listet);
           gv.setAdapter(adapter);
    listcharges=new ArrayList<CustomizedCharge>();
    listcharges.add(new CustomizedCharge(bitMapData, "Loading", "No of Loads", "0", "Cost per Load", "0", "0"));

    listadapter=new FetchlistData(GridActivity.this,listcharges);
    if(listadapter!=null) {
        if (listadapter.getCount() > 0) {
            eview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Intent i = getIntent();
            String textreceived = i.getStringExtra("Selectedname");
            if (textreceived.startsWith("Plucking")) {

                listcharges.add(new CustomizedCharge(bitMapData, "Loading", "No of Loads", "0", "Cost per Load", "0", "0"));
                listadapter=new FetchlistData(GridActivity.this,listcharges);
             } else if (textreceived.startsWith("Loading")) {
                listcharges.add(new CustomizedCharge(bitMapData, "Loading", "No of Loads", "0", "Cost per Load", "0", "0"));
            } else {
               listcharges= databaseHandlerOtherchgs.getAllLabels();
            }

            listview.setAdapter(listadapter);
        }else{
            listview.setEmptyView(eview);
        }

    }

}

Grid Adapter:


public class OtherChargesGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
String totalamount;
AlertDialog alert;
private Activity activity;
byte[] bitMapData;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<OtherChargesType> otherchargestypes;
private List<CustomizedCharge> listactivitycharge;

public OtherChargesGridAdapter(Activity activity, List<OtherChargesType> otherchargestypes) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.otherchargestypes = otherchargestypes;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return otherchargestypes.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return otherchargestypes.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    if (convertview == null) {
        convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.otherchargesgriditem, null);
    }
    OtherChargesType m = otherchargestypes.get(position);
    byte[] outImage = m.getImage();
    ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
    final Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
    ImageView otherimages = (ImageView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    final TextView typename = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    // getting movie data for the row


    typename.setText(m.getTypename());
    otherimages.setImageBitmap(theImage);
    convertview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           if (typename.getText().toString().startsWith("Add New")) {
                final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
                final View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_addnewcharge, null);
                final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
                alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);

                final TextInputLayout txipagetitle = (TextInputLayout) promptView.findViewById(R.id.inputpagetitle);
                final TextInputLayout txiquantitytitle = (TextInputLayout) promptView.findViewById(R.id.inputqunatitytitle);
                final TextInputLayout txiquantity = (TextInputLayout) promptView.findViewById(R.id.inputquantity);
                final TextInputLayout txiratetitle = (TextInputLayout) promptView.findViewById(R.id.inputratetitle);
                final TextInputLayout txirate = (TextInputLayout) promptView.findViewById(R.id.inputrate);
                final EditText edtpagetitle = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.edtpagetitle);
                final EditText edtquantitytitle = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.edtquantitytitle);
                final EditText edtquantity = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.edtquantity);
                final EditText edtratetitle = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.edtratetitle);
                final EditText edtrate = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.edtrate);
                final TextView tvtotal = (TextView) promptView.findViewById(R.id.tvtotalamount);
                final ImageView savedata = (ImageView) promptView.findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
                edtquantity.setText("0.0");
                edtrate.setText("0.0");
                double one = Double.parseDouble(edtquantity.getText().toString());
                double two = Double.parseDouble(edtrate.getText().toString());
                double three = (one * two);
                totalamount = String.valueOf(three);
                tvtotal.setText(totalamount);
                txipagetitle.setError(null);
                txiquantitytitle.setError(null);
                txiquantity.setError(null);
                txiratetitle.setError(null);
                txirate.setError(null);
                edtrate.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                        double one = Double.parseDouble(edtquantity.getText().toString());
                        double two = Double.parseDouble(edtrate.getText().toString());
                        double three = (one * two);
                        totalamount = String.valueOf(three);
                        tvtotal.setText(totalamount);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                savedata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        DatabaseHandlerOtherchgs databaseHandlerOtherchgs = new DatabaseHandlerOtherchgs(activity);
                        if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().isEmpty() & edtquantitytitle.getText().toString().isEmpty() & edtquantity.getText().toString().isEmpty() & edtratetitle.getText().toString().isEmpty() & edtrate.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                            txipagetitle.setError("Enter Title");
                            txiquantitytitle.setError("Enter Quantity Title");
                            txiquantity.setError("Enter Quantity");
                            txiratetitle.setError("Enter Rate Title");
                            txirate.setError("Enter Rate");

                        } else {
                            txipagetitle.setError(null);
                            txiquantitytitle.setError(null);
                            txiquantity.setError(null);
                            txiratetitle.setError(null);
                            txirate.setError(null);
                            String pagetitle = edtpagetitle.getText().toString();
                            String quantitytitle = edtquantitytitle.getText().toString();
                            String quantity = edtquantity.getText().toString();
                            String ratetitle = edtratetitle.getText().toString();
                            String rate = edtrate.getText().toString();
                            String tot = tvtotal.getText().toString();

                            if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("A") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("a")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.a);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("B") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("b")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.b);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();


                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("C") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("c")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.c);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();


                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("D") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("d")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.d);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("E") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("e")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.e);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();


                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("F") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("f")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.f);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();

                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();


                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("G") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("g")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.g);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();


                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("H") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("h")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.h);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();


                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("I") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("i")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.i);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("J") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("j")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.j);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();


                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("K") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("k")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.k);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();


                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("L") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("l")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.l);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();


                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("M") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("m")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.m);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("N") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("n")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.n);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("O") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("o")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.o);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("P") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("p")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.p);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("Q") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("q")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.q);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("R") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("r")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.r);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("S") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("s")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.s);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("T") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("t")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.t);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("U") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("u")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.u);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("V") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("v")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.v);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("W") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("w")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.w);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("X") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("x")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.x);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("Y") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("y")) {
                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.y);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

                            } else if (edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("Z") | edtpagetitle.getText().toString().startsWith("z")) {

                                Resources res = activity.getResources();
                                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.z);
                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

                            }
                            databaseHandlerOtherchgs.insertLabel(bitMapData, pagetitle, quantitytitle, quantity, ratetitle, rate, tot);
                            alert.dismiss();
                            Intent k=activity.getIntent();
                            activity.startActivity(k);

                        }
                    }
                });

                alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alert.show();

           }else if (typename.getText().toString().startsWith("Plucking")) {
               Intent i= new Intent(activity,GridActivity.class);
               i.putExtra("Selectedname","Plucking");
               activity.startActivity(i);

            } else if (typename.getText().toString().startsWith("Loading")) {
               Intent i= new Intent(activity,GridActivity.class);
               i.putExtra("Selectedname","Loading");
               activity.startActivity(i);

            }else {
               String s=typename.getText().toString();
               Intent i= new Intent(activity,GridActivity.class);
               i.putExtra("Selectedname",s);
               activity.startActivity(i);

           }


        }


    });
    return convertview;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnItemSelected Listener with your GridView to achieve this.

```
   AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener gridSelectedListener= new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     //ListView Title 
     title.setText(gridItemsList.get(position).getTitle());
     //ListView Content
     content.setText(gridItemsList.get(position).content());

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
};
yourGridView.setOnItemSelectedListener(gridSelectedListener);
```

Hope it will help you.